# Variable Scope Within "describe" and "it" Statements

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, scope, mocha.js

Below is the code to run a series of tests from a loop. It's producing some unexpected behavior. It seems that the scope of the `args` from the first operation are leaking into the second. To put another way, for some reason `callback` exists within the `args` for the second operation.

```
describe("symlinkType", function() {
  tests.success.forEach(function (test) {
    var args = test[0]
    var expectedType = test[1]
    var should = util.format('should return \'%s\' when src \'%s\'', expectedType, args[0])
    it(should, function (done) {
      var callback = function (err, type) {
        if(err) done(err)
        expect(type).to.equal(expectedType)
        done()
      }
      args.push(callback)
      return symlinkType.apply(null, args)
    })
  })
})

describe("symlinkTypeSync", function()  {
  tests.success.forEach(function (test) {
    var args = test[0]
    var expectedType = test[1]
    var should = util.format('should return \'%s\' when src \'%s\'', expectedType, args[0])
    it(should, function () {
      var value = symlinkTypeSync.apply(null, args)
      expect(value).to.equal(expectedType)
    })
  })
})
```

I'd like a reason for this behavior and how to fix it. I'm used to when you declare a variable it changing the value of the variable and the subsequent `.push()` calls shouldn't be effecting the `args` variable in the second statement. Is this mocha's fault, is the `it` statement leaking scope?

Comment: could you post some example `args` values? What is it's initial value? What is the value after the first push? second push? at the end of  all your tests?

Comment: `var args=test[0]` is just a reference to `test[0]`. A new object is not created. If for some reason `test[0]` points to the same object in memory for all `tests` then the scope of `args` doesn't really mean much. As every cycle references the same object

Comment: @KirillSlatin Your totally right. I believe I need to clone `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commenter @KirillSlatin mentioned `var args=test[0]` is just a reference to the `test[0]` array object, therefore when I `.push()` the callback into the array it pushes it into the original array. Then when I call `test[0]` in the subsequent function its pulling the updated object. This can be prevented by "cloning" the array object, this creates a new one instead of just creating a reference.

```
var args = test[0].slice(0)
```